# PayPal express checkout handling "pending payments" with IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I cant find anny clear documentations about this.
If you use paypal express checkout, when a payment is pending what happens next?
Does paypal sends you by IPN an update if the states changes, do you have options?

Let say you do an DoExpressCheckoutPayment (with NVP)
and you get this:

```
&PAYMENTSTATUS=Pending 
&PENDINGREASON= ECHECK //The payment is pending because it was made by an eCheck that has not yet cleared. 
&REASONCODE=None
```

So you've made the payment and you want to wait until its cleared? What should you do next.

Update Some (external documentation) I found only sugest you could use (IPN?) to handle pending payments.

> "If the Do Express Checkout Payment PENDINGREASON response is a value
>   other than   none or completed , the payment is pending. Typically,
>   this means the customer has paid with aneCheck. In such a case, funds
>   are not guaranteed, and you should not ship or deliver items or
>   services until the payment has successfully completed.   NOTE:
>   PayPal recommends that you block eChecks as a payment method if you
>   are unable tohandle pending state payments.To find out the status of a
>   pending payment, you can:
>
> Submit an Inquiry transaction.
>
> Check the status using PayPal Manager. See PayPal Manager online help
>   for details."

The paypal sandbox seems to have the option to check IPN messages for the express checkout type. The only correlation (if its ment to be used this way) between the DoExpressCheckoutPayment and the IPN seems you can use the "custom" field to keep track of a pending status. The txn_id (ipn) isn't given in DoExpressCheckoutPayment (nvp). Does any one have any experience with this?

Comment: I am getting PENDINGREASON=missing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The transaction ID is most certainly given in DoExpressCheckoutPayment, even if the PAYMENTSTATUS=Pending. A pending payment is still a transaction.

So yes, you would be notified via IPN when the transaction is completed. This typically takes a few working days.
Once it has completed, you can correlate the transaction from DoExpressCheckoutPayment to the IPN you will have received via the txn_id in the IPN.

Note: If you want to test a 'Pending' payment in the PayPal Sandbox, simply go to https://developer.paypal.com/ > Test account and click on 'Payment review' for the seller account you're testing with.
Once payment review is enabled on that seller account, any transactions it receives will be in a 'Pending' state.
Simply disable payment review to release the tranasctions afterwards.

Comment: thanks, This makes sense, the Paypal documentation wan't very clear about this.

Comment: Indeed! Is there a more detailed documentation with information about the "full story" of ExpressCheckout? For example how it is affected by IPN, in what situations a transaction might be pending, what typically can be done in such situations, when should one accept pending transactions and when not to accept, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I thought i'd add my two pence worth of thoughts to this.

I was getting a pending return status using Express Checkout via the dotNet SDK, according to the doc's and examples I should have been getting an 'approved' status.

I couldn't figure out why but it turned out to be because I was passing through a new currency, in our case 'GBP'. I had to log in as the facilitator sandbox account and decide what to do with the new currency.. convert it or setup a new balance in the currency. Once I did this, and set it as the default action, the pending return status no longer occurred.

hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

One thing not noted here and I haven't found anything else to confirm.. is that Paypal Express API doesn't support passing in the NOTIFYURL with the code. So you have to use the hardcoded IPN url set in your paypal account. This of course causes issues because you need a common callback file that can redirect to the individual payment options.

For example, if you are using Paypal Express AND Paypal Advanced.. Neither of those properly support a notifyurl passed in using the code. Paypal Advanced claims to, but it doesn't seem to work. So there needs to be a common IPN callback file that handles the redirection to each.

Unless someone else can confirm a working notify url for Express Checkout variable that can be passed in the code?

Comment: It should work if you specify NOTIFYURL in DoExpressCheckoutPayment. Is this what you do?

Comment: Yes it "should" but does not. I confirmed with Zen-Cart developers a well which is why they had to make a "common" ipn file to handle callbacks from muliple paypal apis. I did find that they have added it in newer versions of their Paypal Express API as "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL" and it does seem to finally work there.. But honestly Paypal has so many API's and they all have a ton of bugs so it's usually hit or miss on what works or not.

Comment: Oh wait.. you said DoExpress.. I only have it in SetExpress.. ok I'll try DoExpress