# Paypal IPN - When the status of transaction will be completed from pending

Tags: paypal

I am working on paypal IPN.

Everything works fine, but i always get "Payment_status" = "Pending" every time even when transaction complete and i receive money in my sandbox account.

I have done googling and get some good post by "Robert", which is perfectly fine.

[see for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314031/paypal-express-checkout-handling-pending-payments-with-ipn)

Make Business account of sandbox --> Payment Review column --> make it disabled.

I got completed status now, very happy.

But, i am confused, what will be the real time scenario.
Or if it is "Enabled" when paypal makes it "Completed", how many days it takes to change the status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will receive a 'Pending' payment if buyers pay via eCheck. An eCheck typically clears within several working days.
Any transactions funded via credit card or PayPal balance will be paid instantly, and thus show up as 'PAYMENTSTATUS=Completed' immediately.

Comment: Robert, i noted that sandbox payment using paypal balance not return "complted" instantanly

Comment: Yes it will. Unless you've got 'Payment review' enabled, which will put all transactions in a 'Pending' state irrespective of funding source.

Comment: @Robert so we have to manually check payment status periodically for complete or still pending ?