# Paypal response code - how to properly handle

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce, paypal-ipn

I'm very new with ecommerce sites and making payments online. I'm building a website for a racetrack company. I built my customer a website where you can order subscriptions, rent gear & rent track days. I got paypal to the point where it is returning to me an IPN and I'm getting the response code coming back as either "Pending" or "Completed".

Once a customer makes a payment I need to update in the database the spots they took up, the gear they rented etc to keep inventory correct.

My question is what is the proper protocol for handling this? Should I assume the payment is good if it comes back as "Pending" & fill up all of the spots in my database & if it later comes back as anything other than "Completed" undo everything? Or is there a better way of handling this?

Also, is there other repsonse codes I should be concerned with from the Paypal IPN?

Finally, is there a way for me to only allow instant payments that I know for sure have gone through so I don't have to deal with 'pending' payments?

Any and all advice on Paypal IPN repsonses and anything related to this is very helpful as I need to release this site in 2 weeks and I want to make sure I don't do something wrong with this.

Comment: This is an old problem - have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314031/paypal-express-checkout-handling-pending-payments-with-ipn

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way for me to only allow instant payments

- There is an account level setting (Payment Receiving Preferences):
  [image: Payment Receiving Preferences]
- In [REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-payment):

  - the `intent` set to `sale` *"is for immediate payment"*
  - [`payment_options`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#paymentoptions-object) of `transaction` (`INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE`)

For good measure, you should still check the status though (for other reasons that might set the status to pending - in the link referenced in comments above, e.g. currency/fraud settings, etc.) and handle according to **your** business rules..

Hth..